# How to get value from a for loop statement

Tags: php, pdo

I am having problem getting the value from a for loop statement.

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($showItems as $items) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php if(!empty($items['ItemCode'])) echo $items['ItemCode'], ' '; ?></td>
<td><img src="<?php if(!empty($items['Sample'])) echo $items['Sample'], ' '; ?>" /></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($items['Name'])) echo $items['Name'], ' '; ?></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($items['Price'])) echo $items['Price'], ' '; ?><input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="<?php if(!empty($items['Price'])) echo $items['Price'], ' '; ?>"/></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($items['Description'])) echo $items['Description'], ' '; ?></td>            
    <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty[]" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>
    <td ><input type="submit" value="Add to Registry" onClick="addRegistry(<?php echo $items['ItemCode'];  ?>)"></td>               
  </tr>         
<?php } ?>
```

I test it by echoing the value input on the textbox.

```
function addRegistry(pid){
//alert(qty);
    document.form.pid.value=pid;
    document.form.command.value='add';
    document.form.submit();
}

if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];
 echo "<script>alert('<?php echo $qty; ?>');</script>";
}
```

I was able to get the last data, but the other aren't available.

Comment: Try adding a print_r($showItems); at your first line and post what is the output.

Comment: hi @MarcoAurélioDeleu!i dont think we need to use print_r here, i only want to echo the inputted qty on the 3 datas.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu let say for the for loop statement i got 3 datas, input type 1(quantity1), input type 2(quantity2), input type 3(quantity3), i would like to echo it using this script echo "<script>alert('<?php echo $qty; ?>');</script>";, i was able to echo input type 3(quantity3) when i inputted 10, but when i put value on 1 or 2 it doesnt have any value.

Comment: IDs must be unique.  Fix that and try again.